# setting up bridged adapter for VPN server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, bridge

I have an Ubuntu linux Linode server that I am trying to install OpenVPN on. I'm following the tutorials (which, it turns out, are quite incomplete).

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.10
        network 192.168.0.0
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 192.168.0.255
        gateway 192.168.0.1
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_fd 9
        bridge_hello 2
        bridge_maxage 12
        bridge_stp off
```

When I add this chunk in my /etc/network/interfaces, and I restart networking, my eth0 interface does not have an IP and I cannot get on the network (I need to use a buggy, slow, and annoying AJAX term to do damage repair).

Why does adding this screw everything up? Any tips on how to set up this bridged adapter??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you install the `bridge-utils` package?  Try testing in a VM on your local machine before testing network configurations on systems you don't have access to.

Comment: In a bridged setup, your eth0 will NOT have an IP, the bridge does. If you don't need bridging, remove the br0 device config and set up eth0.

Comment: Can you please add the output of `brctl show` and `ifconfig eth0`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this lines:

```
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback 

    auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet dhcp

    auto br0
    iface br0 inet dhcp
          bridge_ports eth0
```

DHCP is easier than static. At least for me it worked this way.